# Voice Reachability in iOS

Tags: ios, reachability

I have the reachability class working in my app for cellular data (WWAN) and WiFi. I'm curious if anyone has found a way to determine voice reachability as the cell network sometimes provides voice call capability without data traffic.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to know whether a SIM card is installed, i.e. not if there’s currently any coverage, you can create an instance of the Core Telephony framework’s [`CTTelephonyNetworkInfo`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo/Reference/Reference.html) class and check if its `subscriberCellularProvider` property is set.

Comment: Jakob - thanks for the tip!  It also looks like the mobileNetworkCode property of CTCarrier will tell when the phone is out of service range, assuming the device has a SIM card and is not in airplane mode.  I'll give it a try and post results.